# Custom ukelele layout - cmd-w and similar shortcuts not working

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, ukelele

I'm making a custom non-latin keyboard layout in Ukelele. When I install the layout and activate it typical OS hotkeys like Cmd-W or Cmd-Q are not working, but when I switch to say Russian layout - all hotkeys work as usual.

How to make the layout respect typical hotkeys? Is there a setting somewhere that I'm missing?

// I'm using latest versions of Ukelele and Mac OS.

Comment: What was your staring point for your custom layout?  Try using Russian, since you know that works.

Comment: I started with blank

Comment: Start instead with Russian or something that already works.  Ukelele provides a bunch of keyboards with the app download.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, guys, found an answer already.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is solved by going to Modifiers tab and adding one for CMD down key, then selecting to switch to QWERTY layout when CMD is pressed. Same can be repeated for CMD+SHIFT down.